# Stripe Payment Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, third-party-module, stripe

Does anybody has used stripe payment module for Magento 2?
I need a suggestion for stripe payment module. Alos need Apple pay and Android Pay.
Please, guys, suggest me a good working module which you might have used for your store and working well.

Alos have any idea for google products and bing products (Magento 2)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Free Module: https://github.com/pmclain/module-stripe

Comment: Have you used it? and is it working properly?

Comment: I have not used but you can try it on local machine and proper test it.

Answer (score 2):

There are some modules are available,if you use paid module then you don't need to worry about module support.Module team will provide you 6 month free service

You can choose one of below

https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-module-stripe.html

https://www.magedelight.com/magento2-stripe-payment-module.html

For Free module you can check install it on your local machine and after fully test you can use it on live server.

https://github.com/pmclain/module-stripe

Hope this will help you.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check the Magento Marketplace for Stripe payment modules that have positive reviews and ratings from other users. You can choose at https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-module-stripe-global.html
Additionally, there are extensions available for integrating Apple Pay and Android Pay with Magento 2. As for Google and Bing products, you may want to consider using extensions that allow you to easily manage your product feeds and campaigns on these platforms.